# What is meaning of Azure Key Vault Reference different icon colors in configuration on Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azureportal

I can understand the meaning of red & green icons of Azure key vault reference come in configuration on Azure portal, but couldn't found the meaning of blue icon (shown in snapshot below).

[image]

Any help

Comment: Does it show anything if you hover over the icon with your mouse

Comment: @PeterBons No !!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when trying to use "User Assigned Managed Identities".
It appears that App Services will automatically use the "System Managed Identity" for Key Vault References, even if there is none configured.

You can however tell Azure to use a specific managed identity using Azure CLI or Powershell (or bicep) by setting the "**keyVaultReferenceIdentity**" as documented here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#access-vaults-with-a-user-assigned-identity

```
userAssignedIdentityResourceId=$(az identity show -g MyResourceGroupName -n MyUserAssignedIdentityName --query id -o tsv)
appResourceId=$(az webapp show -g MyResourceGroupName -n MyAppName --query id -o tsv)
az rest --method PATCH --uri "${appResourceId}?api-version=2021-01-01" --body "{'properties':{'keyVaultReferenceIdentity':'${userAssignedIdentityResourceId}'}}"
```

Once I updated this, the blue icon changed to that magical green checkbox! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Green means it was able to perform the authentication / retrieve the secret.

Red means there's something wrong. (It can be a network security rule for example)

No marks, probably it's not using Key Vault References

Comment: what about "blue"?

Comment: I think it falls in the third one too

Comment: but I had configured Key Vault reference in that case.

Comment: @Rahul: Could you please share us the steps to land into the page ( as per your screen shot)

Answer (score 0):

The blue circle means "The portal is not able to confirm the status of your Key Vault reference at this time. Please confirm the status directly from the app by checking whether the environment variables have resolved".

Click on the on name of the environment variable which is showing the blue circle. From there click"Click here to access the app".
In the page that opens up, you can validate whether or not your Key vault access works by clicking on the "App Settings".