# Bicep KeyVaultReferenceIdentity in Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-managed-identity, azure-bicep

I'm trying to change an Azure function app which currently uses a System Assigned identity to connect to a KeyVault to a User Assigned Managed Identity. The UAMI has the correct permissions to the KeyVault , but I'm struggling with the sparesly documented `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` property in bicep. Below is the code for my module.

```
param uamiId string=''

resource functionApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  name: functionAppName
  location: 'uks'
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: empty(uamiId)? {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }:{
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${uamiId}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appPlansprimaryId
    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false// 64 bit
      keyVaultReferenceIdentity: uamiId
    }
    httpsOnly: true
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: uamiId
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the keyVaultReferenceIdentity is in two places. If I comment out the first reference, the app does reference it in JSON view, but only in one place, the other reference to it in the JSON  config is null. If I deploy the bicep script with both references, the deployment completely screws p and it changes back to SystemAssigned in the JSON view. Are both needed? Is something else needed? There seems to be no way of doing this via the portal. The only pointer I can find is this post which suggests a powershell script https://stackoverflow.com/a/72531566/30512

Answer (score 1):

***Purpose of keyVaultReferenceIdentity in two places:***

1. Firstly, `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` under `properties` block is for specifying the `User Managed Identity` that will be used by the function app during runtime for interactions with the Key Vault, like retrieving or updating secrets.
2. The `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` under `site config` block is used to specify the `User Managed Identity` that can be used specifically for accessing `Key Vault references` within the function app's configuration settings.

***Note***: Adding to the above, including `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` field is completely depends on your requirement. Adding `keyVaultReferenceIdentity` only in the `properties` block will also be sufficient to achieve your output.

Coming to your bicep code, you need to pass identity id `keyVaultReferenceIdentity: uamiId.id` with key vault reference field but not `keyVaultReferenceIdentity: uamiId`.

*Modified code has given below.*

```bash
param uidentity string = 'newuser'
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param functionappname string = 'latestfuncj'
param appServicePlanName string = 'newjpla'

resource identity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
   name: uidentity
   location: location
}

resource plan 'Microsoft.Web/serverfarms@2021-02-01' = {
  name: appServicePlanName
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  sku: {
    name: 'Y1'
  }
  properties: {
  }
}

resource functionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-01-01' = {
  name: functionappname
  location: location
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${identity.id}' : {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: plan.id
    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      keyVaultReferenceIdentity: identity.id
    }
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: identity.id
    httpsOnly: true
  }
}
```

*Deployment succeeded:*

[image]

***References:***

[Blog](https://larry.claman.net/post/2021-08-19-21-bicep-uami/) | [Larry Claman](https://larry.claman.net/)

[Complete Bicep code](https://gist.github.com/dazfuller/7a61bf3dbf7be1b977c9fa54e7cdf17d) for deploying an Azure Function app with Key Vault references.

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation makes sense. I'm actually passing the managedIdentity.Id in as a string to the module, so it's already in  the correct format. I eventually managed to get this working with the code posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I gt this working by using only the in the properties block:

```
properties: {
    serverFarmId: plan.id
    siteConfig: {
      ftpsState: 'FtpsOnly'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      use32BitWorkerProcess : false
      //keyVaultReferenceIdentity: identity.id // don't need this one
    }
    keyVaultReferenceIdentity: identity.id
    httpsOnly: true
  }
```

Then specifying the correct managed identity ID in the `AZURE_CLIENT_ID` app setting and grabbing this to pass as a connection string to the keyvault. This is the Client ID, not the Principal ID:

```
private static async Task<SecretBundle> GetSecret(KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient, string secretName)
{
    return await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(SecretUri(secretName));
}
public static string SecretUri(string secret)
{
    return (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("kvUri")+"/Secrets/"+secret).Replace("//Secrets", "/Secrets");
}

...

var serviceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider(connectionString: "RunAs=App;AppId="+ Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID"));
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(serviceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var mySecret = await GetSecret(keyVaultClient, "NameOfMySecret");
```

The app setting `kvUri` is the full name of the KV - eg: https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/